# Halving number at regular intervals vs same number at doubling intervals.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The infinite series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  2^{-n}$ converges to 2.

If I was given an apple after one day, half an apple after another day, a quarter of an apple after another day, and so on, I would never quite get two apples.

In my (very limited) understanding, and apple-a-day is the same as two-apples-per-two-days or half-an-apple-per-12-hours.

If I was given an apple after one day, another apple after a further **two** days, another apple after another **four** days, etc., I would have an unending supply of apples.

Why are these two different answers, and how is this difference expressed mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to spread out the apples over several days doesn't become $1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots$. It becomes
$$
1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\cdots
$$
The first apple has one day all on its own. The second apple is spread out over two days, giving you two half apples. The third apple is spread out over 4 days, giving you four quarter apples. And so on.

It isn't surprising that one approach gives more apples than the other.

Comment: Thanks, your series makes my misunderstanding obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1 apple after 2 days does not result in the same amount of apple as half an apple after one day. Rather 1 apple after 2 days results in the same amount of apple as half an apple after one day followed by another half apple after 1 day.